# php - Why can't you define a constant named EMPTY

Tags: php, constants

So... This is more of a curiosity, not a real problem. I don't get this:

```
<?php
     define('EMPTY', 1);
     echo EMPTY;
```

Results in: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '('

My first thought is that empty is reserved for the empty function. But then I tried:

```
<?php
     define('IS_ARRAY', 1);
     echo IS_ARRAY;
```

Result: 1

So... I don't get it. Why empty can't be used as constant while for example is_array, die, etc. can.

Comment: can you point out why? checked the manual, nothing special there. searched google... well... empty is a very common word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`empty` is not a function but a language construct (more like an operator than a function), which means it's resolved by the parser at parse time and not by the runtime. It's a reserved keyword and you cannot use it for anything yourself like function names, or constants.

The reason `empty` cannot be a regular function is because it behaves differently. `empty($undefined)` would first resolve `$undefined`, throw an error, then pass `null` to `empty`; which is exactly the case `empty` is supposed to prevent, so it cannot play by the normal function invocation rules.

Comment: Can't accept for 9 minutes. Will accept it then. Still... I don't get why manual doesn't mention this. empty is listed under "functions" section.

Answer (score 2):

`empty` is a reserved keyword in PHP. You cannot use any [reserved](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) words as constants, class names, function or method names as these words have special meaning in PHP. Use any other name as constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can definately define "EMPTY" as a constant. The problem is you can't use it directly.

```
<?php 
 define("EMPTY", "valueForEmpty");
 echo EMPTY; // Wont work because empty is a keyword and PHP doesn't know that you mean the constant.

 echo constant("EMPTY"); // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the reserved keywords are also case insensitive, and they can't be defined as constant or redefined using **runkit_function_redefine()**;

You can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) the exhaustive list of reserved keywords

Comment: I think you mean case insensitive.